# A function which join a various amount of string columns using args

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

The goal is to create a function which can join and *args amount of columns with string values. This could be done vectorized or by for loops.

I have attempted the following code:

```
 class Manipulation(pd.DataFrame):

    def join_strings(self, *args):

         new_col = "".join(self[args])
         return new_col


    ha = join_strings1('col1', 'col2', 'col3')
```

The error is the following:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: `self[args]` doesn't make sense. `args` is a list on its own. Unless you failed to provide relevant bit of code showing us what class this is.

Comment: the class inherits from pd.dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Since, your question is not clear and you have not provided us with class. Are you looking for something like this?

```
def join_strings(*args):
  new_col = "".join(args)
  return new_col

print(join_strings('col1', 'col2', 'col3'))

#output
col1col2col3
```

Comment: The result should be a new column which adds the other two or more columns